# Django-templates: Why doesn't {% if "string"|length > 10 %} work at all?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.3.  If I put the following fragment into my template:

```
{% if 'my string'|length > 10 %}{{ 'my string'|length }}{% endif %}
```

the rendering engine prints '9'.  The only thing I can think of is that the `|length` filter is returning a string, but that seems odd in the extreme.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The length I actually want to test comes from `flatpage.title` provided by `django.contrib.flatpages`.  For this reason, I'd rather not hack the view to provide the information I need to the template.  I'd hoped I could simply use the `|length` filter as described in the [Django docs, here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filters).  However, as has been pointed out, the only way to do this seems to be to also use the `|get_digit` filter, whose behaviour is not clearly defined in this respect. :(

Comment: This is no longer the case with django 1.10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, filters always return a string.

You can achive the desired functionality by calculating string length in a view and do something like this:

```
{% if str_length > 10 %}
    {{ str_length }}
{% endif %}
```

Or create a custom filter for your needs: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BasicComparisonFilters

*Edited for typo*

Comment: actually my specific use-case is with `{{ flatpage.title }}`, so I really wanted to avoid doing it myself in a view.  However, it's touch-and-go whether it makes more sense to extend `django.contrib.flatpages` or to write my own filter.  Thanks :)

Comment: btw -- don't you think it's a little odd that the `|length` filter doesn't return something which can be compared with a number?  It's used like that here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filters

Comment: thanks, this is the correct answer to my question.  It doesn't help me much (I was aware of those two options, of course), but it **is** the right answer to my question :)

Answer (score 14):

I'm **recommending not using this** but I have combined the `get_digit` and the `length` filters before to make this work.

```
{% if "12345678901234567890"|length|get_digit:"-1" > 20 %} 
    {{ "12345678901234567890"|length }} 
{% endif %}
```

results in nothing in the template, but:

```
{% if "12345678901234567890"|length|get_digit:"-1" > 19 %} 
    {{ "12345678901234567890"|length }} 
{% endif %}
```

results in:

```
20
```

being printed.

Comment: Thanks -- this does work, though, as you intimate, it's a slightly dangerous hack.

Answer (score 9):

I know its late but as per django 2.1 your code will work. Please see below reference
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#filters

```
{% if messages|length >= 100 %}
   You have lots of messages today!
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following conditional:
{% if flatpage.title.10 %}

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create variable like this:

```
{% with 'my_string'|length as string_length %}
    your code when you have available as INT variable string_length
{% endwith %}
```

Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Going to play devil's advocate here and ask why is this necessary in the first place? It's one thing if you're calculating on the value of a variable, but if it's a hard-coded value, just put it in there in the right form. All you're doing is adding processing overhead for something that's static.

Comment: well, yes, of course it's for a variable... :)  Moreover, it's for a variable provided by a view I didn't write myself, and would rather not hack if I can help it, hence the question.  I'll update my question to make that a little clearer, perhaps :)